# Sum and Ranking

Tags: excel, if-statement, rank

I currently have each row providing a sum for "Total Score". Then, I have the "Placing" column to rank.

I am having an issue when there is a "0" for a score, my rank will show "1". A simple solution is to delete my sum for those rows, but I want the sum to remain as is because the scoring portion of the excel sheet will be protected.

I would like the Placing to be blank or show "0" when there is a total score of "0".

- My calculation to provide rank (column V) `=RANK(O22,$O$9:$O$58,1)`
- My calculation to provide placing (column P) `=IF(V22>15,"16",V22)`

Your time and help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
=MAX(0,RANK(O22,$O$9:$O$58, 1)-COUNTIF(O:O,0))
```

It'll prevent the "0s" from going negative, and leave them displayed as 0's. You could leave the MAX off, however, they'll display as negatives then. Either way ..

Alternately, if you can not show "0", but leave the cell blank, it won't consider it in the RANK function.